# Xcode Save for Development Deployment option is missing

Tags: ios, xcode6

I'm a complete noob for Xcode and Mac, building a Phonegap app so using them just for exporting the IPA.

I'm using Xcode 6.3.2.

I'm in the "Select a method to export" dialog and wishing to "Save for Development Deployment" (in order for my IPA to be debug-enabled), which is the forth option in the dialog according to this [Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html). Unfortunately, in my Mac I have only the three top options.
(I would have been happy to illustrate with images but SO doesn't let me yet, sorry)

Where is this option? Why can't I see it there?
I must have my IPA debug-enabled to solve a sneaky bug.

Thank you! :)

Comment: are you code signing with a development provisioning profile?

Comment: also check when you click on your app target at the top left next to the stop button, go edit scheme -> archive then see if changing the build config to debug helps

Comment: @Fonix thank you, I *think* I do, I have all of the provisioning profiles showing in Xcode->Preferences->Accounts->View Details. Some of them are development type, I don't know if and how they are taken into account though.

Also, I verified and I did edit all the schemes's build configs to "Debug" instead of "Release".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is available in Xcode 7, not 6.

Comment: Thanks, I updated to 7 and the option was finally available.